# problem with common_msgs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I try to build a package, I get this error:

dede@ubuntu:~/electric_workspace/sandbox/labrob_ros_quadrotor$ rosmake labrob_quadrotor_sensors
.
.
.
.
In file included from /home/dede/electric_workspace/sandbox/labrob_ros_quadrotor/labrob_quadrotor_sensors/include/labrob_quadrotor_sensors/labrob_gazebo_camera.h:74:0,
from /home/dede/electric_workspace/sandbox/labrob_ros_quadrotor/labrob_quadrotor_sensors/src/labrob_gazebo_camera.cpp:31:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/diagnostics/diagnostic_updater/include/diagnostic_updater/diagnostic_updater.h:47:41: fatal error: common_msgs/DiagnosticArray.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
.
.
but

dede@ubuntu:~/electric_workspace/sandbox/labrob_ros_quadrotor$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-common-msgs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ros-electric-common-msgs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 406 not upgraded.

what can I do to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47257/problem-with-common_msgs/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2012-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Very weird error. Normally, the include line in diagnostic_updater should not include `common_msgs/DiagnosticArray.h` but `diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray.h`. Try reinstalling the stack diagnostics:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-electric-diagnostics`
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3